# How to convert panoramas to sliding video/gif?

Tags: video, panorama

I am trying convert a panorama image with very high width to height ratio. I want this to be visible on a mobile app i.e. facebook or instagram as a video from left end to right.

Comment: Maybe see: http://www.summitpost.org/7-ways-to-post-panoramas-to-sp/241488 for some HTML coding ideas that get a scrollable pano display, rather than video conversion.

Answer (score 1):

A panoramic photo, or inclusive a 360°x180° spherical view compresses in a single image a hole range of angles that are considered normal. So you need to get rid of that doing some kind of crop.

The first aproach is using a "panorama viewer" where you can interactivly pan and tilt, inclusive zoom in and out. https://www.google.com/search?q=panorama+viewer There are some standalone programs or web based ones.

The second one is to use that as a base for a video. Again, there are some options that does that automaticly: https://www.google.com/search?q=panorama+to+video

You could use a video editing tool like http://www.serif.com/free-video-editing-software/ where you drop your image, and move arround the framing, then exporting it as a video.

[image]

You are a bit limited here, becouse it des not correct the distortion, specially on the upper and lower angles of an 360x180 image (spherical projection) But could work well on a simple panoramic image.

Comment: Thanks, I could not sign up with serif to get a copy of the software. Any ubuntu alternative. I could a way to do in mac.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a dead easy way to do it in mac.

Just import the image into a new movie in iMovie and stretch the image along the timeline for the length you want the output movie to be.

That's it. Here is a sample I generated

https://flic.kr/p/BC422a